# how to get max column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

here is a sample table:

```
Create table #TableA (ID INT
                             , [1] DECIMAL(6,5)
                             ,[1.1] DECIMAL(6,5)
                             , [2] DECIMAL(6,5)
                             ,[2.2] DECIMAL(6,5)
                             , [3] DECIMAL(6,5)
                             ,[3.3] DECIMAL(6,5)
                             , [4] DECIMAL(6,5)
                             ,[4.4] DECIMAL(6,5)
                             , FLAGB1 CHAR(1)
                             , FLAGB2 float)
INSERT INTO #TABLEA (ID, [1],[1.1],[2],[2.2],[3],[3.3],[4],[4.4],FLAGB1,FLAGB2  )
VALUES(1, 1.1111,null, 2.2222,0.1234, 3.3333,null,null, 1.4444,'y',null )
         , (2, null,1.2345, 2.2345,null, 3.2345, 4.2345,1.5437,0.2378,null,null)
         ,(3, 5.3789,1.2222,0.23864,null, 2.2222, 3.2222, 4.2222,null,'y',null)
Drop #TableA
```

I need column FLAGB2 to get the "MAX" column-names if FLAGB1 is 'Y'. apologies, i couldn't put the requirement in a sentence(s) more clearly, so the result should look like this:

```
> [ID]  [1]     [1.1]   [2]     [2.2]   [3]     [3.3]   [4]     [4.4]   [FLAGB1]   [FLAGB2]
> 1     1.11110 NULL    2.22220 0.12340 3.33330 NULL    NULL    1.44440  y          4.4
> 2     NULL    1.23450 2.23450 NULL    3.23450 4.23450 1.54370 0.23780  NULL       NULL
> 3     5.37890 1.22220 0.23864 NULL    2.22220 3.22220 4.22220 NULL     y          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't have a `greatest()` function.  You can do this painfully with a `case` statement:

```
update #tableA
    set flagB2 = (case when [1] >= [1.1] and [1] >= [2] and [1] >= [2.2] and
                            [1] >= [3] and [1] >= [3.3] and [1] >= [4] and [1] >= [4.4]
                       then 1
                       when [2] >= [1] and [2] >= [1.1] and  and [2] >= [2.2] and
                            [2] >= [3] and [2] >= [3.3] and [2] >= [4] and [2] >= [4.4]
                       then 2
                       . . .
                  end)
    where flagB1 = 'y';
```

This type of data structure leads me to suspect that the columns `[1]` - `[4.4]` are related.  That typically means that you should have an association/junction table with one row per `id` and one row for each of these values.  The query would be much easier to write using that data structure.

Comment: this wouldn't work because the actual table has about 60 columns. Just to make it clear, there is nothing to do with the values of the columns. its the column itself that has to be the highest(except nulls) if there is 'Y' on FLAB1.
FLAGB2 should be populated by column names [4.4] and [4] regardless of its  row values.

Comment: @sqlsean . . . It will work, it just makes for a very long query.  However, your requirement further strengthens my opinion that this information should be in an association/junction table.

Comment: sorry may be i was not clear ... i don't want the column names with highest value under it. i need FLAGB2 to get column names with any value under it(except null) but itself is the highest than other columns and also has 'Y' for FLAGB1........ 

the column names came from concatenation of two different columns form two different tables...if that what you meant by junction table?

Comment: @sqlsean . . . I modified the example to return the name of the column rather than the value.  A junction table would be a table with one row per value in this row.  It would have at least three columns, `id`, `columnname`, and `columnvalue`.  In other words, the data would be stored in rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The following will allow for changes to the table schema. It looks like you could use some tolerance based on what you've shown. I went with a cursor as I could see no way to use the server's reflection functions in a "raw" update statement. But I think it improves upon hard-coding the columns in the script.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY,
  [1] DECIMAL(6,5),
  [1.1] DECIMAL(6,5),
  [2] DECIMAL(6,5),
  [2.2] DECIMAL(6,5),
  [3] DECIMAL(6,5),
  [3.3] DECIMAL(6,5),
  [4] DECIMAL(6,5),
  [4.4] DECIMAL(6,5),
  FLAGB1 CHAR(1),
  FLAGB2 float)

INSERT INTO #TABLEA (ID,[1],[1.1],[2],[2.2],[3],[3.3],[4],[4.4],FLAGB1,FLAGB2)
VALUES(1, 1.1111,null, 2.2222,0.1234, 3.3333,null,null, 1.4444,'y',null )
         , (2, null,1.2345, 2.2345,null, 3.2345, 4.2345,1.5437,0.2378,null,null)
         ,(3, 5.3789,1.2222,0.23864,null, 2.2222, 3.2222, 4.2222,null,'y',null)

-- The following will run a separate UPDATE statement for every column having a numeric name on the #TableA temp table

-- Get all column names from the temp table (thus tempdb's INFORMATION_SCHEMA) that are numeric and put them in a new temp table, #columns
SELECT Column_Name
INTO #columns
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '#TableA%'
  AND ISNUMERIC(Column_Name) = 1

DECLARE @column_name varchar(80)

-- Create a cursor to loop through the contents of #columns 
DECLARE cur_columns CURSOR FOR
  SELECT 
    Column_Name 
  FROM 
    #columns 
  ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(decimal, Column_Name)

OPEN cur_columns
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_columns INTO @column_name

-- For each numeric column name...
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

  -- Build an UPDATE statement dynamically
  -- Update the FLAGB2 column with the column name for this iteration given the value in that column is not null and FLAGB1 is either 'y' or 'Y'
  SET @SQL = '
    UPDATE #TableA SET
      FLAGB2 = ' + @column_name + '
    WHERE
      ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ' IS NOT NULL
      AND UPPER(FLAGB1) = ''Y'''

  -- Execute the UPDATE statement
  EXEC(@SQL)

  FETCH NEXT FROM cur_columns INTO @column_name
END

CLOSE cur_columns
DEALLOCATE cur_columns

SELECT * FROM #TableA
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the input but the your query doesn't seem to do anything, my knowledge is very limited about cursors, after i execute the your query, it does not update the table!! am i missing something? can you give me more instructions to make this work?

Comment: OK, I've added your table creation and population logic from your question and a SELECT statement at the end to check contents of #TableA. In my tests, #TableA is updated correctly. Compare my full script with yours to determine how it differs and, thus, what went wrong in yours.